# Could not launch intent Intent

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

Here my Espresso's tests:

```
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockResponse
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer
import org.junit.After
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TradersActivityTest {
    private lateinit var mockServer: MockWebServer

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var tradersIntentTestRule = IntentsTestRule(TradersActivity::class.java, false, false)

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        mockServer = MockWebServer()
        mockServer.start(8081)
    }

    @Test
fun hasTraders_noTradersTextView_isNotDisplayed() {
    mockServer.enqueue(MockResponse()
            .setResponseCode(200)
            .setBody(FileUtil.getStringFromFile(context, ONE_TRADER_NO_WALLETS_LIST)));
    tradersIntentTestRule.launchActivity(Intent())
    onView(withId(R.id.noTradersTextView))
            .check(matches(not(isDisplayed())))
}

    @Test
    fun toolBar_height() {
        onView(withId(R.id.toolBar))
                .check(matches(withHeightResId(R.dimen.tool_bar_height)))
    }
```

Test `hasTraders_noTradersTextView_isNotDisplayed` success pass.

But test `toolBar_height` fail with message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?
at androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.waitForAtLeastOneActivityToBeResumed(RootViewPicker.java:169)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.get(RootViewPicker.java:83)
```

So I change `setup` method:

```
 @Before
    fun setup() {
        mockServer = MockWebServer()
        mockServer.start(8081)

        mockServer.enqueue(MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(200)
                .setBody(FileUtil.getStringFromFile(context, ONE_TRADER_NO_WALLETS_LIST)));
        tradersIntentTestRule.launchActivity(Intent())

        Debug.d(TAG, "SUCCCESS_START_MOCKWEBSRVER")
    }
```

Now test `toolBar_height` pass, but `hasTraders_noTradersTextView_isNotDisplayed` fail with message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent { flg=0x10000000 com.myproject.android.ui.activity.TradersActivity } within 45 seconds. Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time? There could be an animation or something constantly repainting the screen. Or the activity is doing network calls on creation? See the threaddump logs. For your reference the last time the event queue was idle before your activity launch request was 1556373134135 and now the last time the queue went idle was: 1556373143180. If these numbers are the same your activity might be hogging the event queue.
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:459)
```

P.S. I need to start activity in test `hasTraders_noTradersTextView_isNotDisplayed` because it's a specific test.
But I wan't to start activity in test `toolBar_height`

Comment: I think you need to use a IdlingResource to wait for the view to be shown

Answer (score 0):

In my UI automated tests, I have this classes:

```
public class UiTestHelper {

    public static Matcher<View> childAtPosition(
            final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int position) {

        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("Child at position " + position + " in parent ");
                parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
                return parent instanceof ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                        && view.equals(((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(position));
            }
        };
    }

    public static void clickOn(View view) {
        waitUntilVisible(view);
        onView(withId(view.getId())).perform(click());
    }

    public static void waitUntilVisible(View view) {
        ViewVisibilityIdlingResource idlingResource = new ViewVisibilityIdlingResource(view, VISIBLE);
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(idlingResource);
    }

    public static void unregisterAllIdlingResources() {
        IdlingRegistry idlingRegistry = IdlingRegistry.getInstance();
        for (IdlingResource resource: idlingRegistry.getResources()) {
            idlingRegistry.unregister(resource);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ViewVisibilityIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {

    private final View view;
    private final int expectedVisibility;
    private boolean idle;
    private ResourceCallback resourceCallback;

    public ViewVisibilityIdlingResource(final View view, final int expectedVisibility) {
        this.view = view;
        this.expectedVisibility = expectedVisibility;
        this.idle = false;
        this.resourceCallback = null;
    }

    @Override
    public final String getName() {
        return ViewVisibilityIdlingResource.class.getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean isIdleNow() {
        idle = idle || (view.getVisibility() == expectedVisibility && view.getWidth() > 0 && view.getHeight() > 0);

        if (idle) {
            if (resourceCallback != null) {
                resourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
            }
        }

        return idle;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
        this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback;
    }

}
```

Then when I want to check that a view is there I call

```
UiTestHelper.waitUntilVisible(view);
```